# Anyway to encapsulate tailwinds styles?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to integrate Tailwind into an existing project, and it started to mess up the styling of existing elements.

Is there anyway we can encapsulate styles into a class?

For example, I created an element `<div class="myapp"> ..{tailwind}.. <div>`, where `{tailwind}` is the new elements with tailwind classes.

In this case, I can encapsulate the style under `myapp` class, and all the styles will only applied for children of `myapp` class?

I tried to search but couldn't find it.

Many thanks

Search on google, read tailwind document, play around with the configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found 2 ways to do it

1. Use `important` in the tailwind.config file. This option will automatically add a prefix selector into all tailwind generated classes. For more details, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important
2. Use `postcss-prefixwrap` plugin. This option will add a selector prefix into all classes and selectors from our css files, including ones that are not related to tailwind. For more details, see https://github.com/dbtedman/postcss-prefixwrap

Note that you shouldn't use both, since `postcss-prefixwrap` will also add another wrapper selector on top of tailwind prefix.

I ended up using the 2nd option because the 1st option exclude some of css files

Comment: Could you clarify what are the downsides of the 1st option?

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind supports children elements styling via [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants):

```
<div class="[&_p]:text-[24px]">
  <p>Every text in the p tag will now have font-size equal to 24px.</p>
  <p>The same is here</p>
</div>
<p>Here text will have usual style as it is out of tailwind scope</p>
```

Please notice that tailwind adds default CSS styles, which can be customized or totally opted out in the [config file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration).